# How do I subtract two numbers in R?

Tags: r

I am somewhat new to R. While I was writing a function involving some arithmetic, I got a surprising result.

```
SubtractSeven <- function(x) {
return (x - 7)
}
SubtractSeven(9)
```

Here is the output:

```
> SubtractSeven <- function(x) {
+   return (x - 7)
+ }
> SubtractSeven(9)
Error in `-`(x, 7) : could not find function "-"
```

I then played around with some arithmetic operators in the console, and here is what I got:

```
> 5+4
[1] 9
> 5*4
[1] 20
> 5/4
[1] 1.25
> 5^4
[1] 625
> 5-4
Error in `-`(5, 4) : could not find function "-"
> -5
Error in `-`(5) : could not find function "-"
> +5
[1] 5
```

What in the world is going on!?
I have "bigmemory" and "seqinr" packages loaded.

Comment: couldn't repreoduce the error (`SubtractSeven(9)
#[1] 2`)
can you check whether you copied `-` wrong

Comment: Copying and pasting the dash you sent me in your comment still gives me an error!

Comment: ok, may be some issue on your R console.  Please try to do this on a fresh R session

Comment: Hi, loading a fresh R session fixes the problem! However, I have gigabytes of data loaded in my current session and am reluctant to save and re-open the workspace. Is there nothing I can do to fix subtraction in the current session?

Comment: Not clear what went wrong.  May be you can do `.Primitive("-")(7, 5)#
[1] 2`

Comment: @akrun Thank you! This did the trick. You can post your comment as an answer if you would like me to accept it as the right answer.

Comment: thanks, posted as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `.Primitive` if we need to make use of the `-` in the current session

```
.Primitive("-")(7, 5)
```

In the function, it would be

```
SubtractSeven <- function(x) {
    .Primitive("-")(x, 7)
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you copy-pasted the code? Try removing the minus symbol and introducing it again by you. Sometimes when you copy a code from a web page it introduces a "─" instead of a "-".

Answer (score 1):

If `'-'` has been replaced by something else in your session, you can use `match.fun`.

```
SubtractSeven <- function(x)  match.fun('-')(9, x)

SubtractSeven(7)
#[1] 2
SubtractSeven(5)
#[1] 4
```